# Recursive UNION ALL to parse string taking very long

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, union, common-table-expression

I am trying to speed up this recursive UNION ALL as shown below, but I cannot think how to do it. Maybe a while loop but I am not sure. The movement data is stored as one long string of encoded movement data and the script recursively calls the select statement to parse/extract this data and then it is all casted.

I would really like to understand more about speeding up recursive union all's or finding another way. I don't believe indexing is a problem so this is not really a possible solution.

"RouteData" is the long string that is parsed by fixed length intervals.

Here is a sample of the encoded data:

```
ScenarioPID : 3
LegID  :1
RoutePart : 0x0000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000
RouteData : 0x40323AAAAAAAAAAB00013FA6FFD663CCA3310000001F00403 ... (goes on)
cnt : 37
sequence : 1
StartTime : 8828
```

---

The final output data looks like this for one track.

```
ScenarioPID LegID   sequence    TrackID Offset  TimeOffset  Length  StartTime
3             1        1           1      0         0        6300    8828
3             1        2           1      0.0449    31       6300    8828
3             1        3           1      0.8942    325      6300    8828
3             1        4           1      0.9736    356      6300    8828
3             1        5           1      1         369      6300    8828
```

---

```
USE nss_demo;

DECLARE @scenario1 INT;
DECLARE @DAY_START INT;
DECLARE @DAY_END INT;
DECLARE @TRAIN_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @TRACK_TYPE VARCHAR(50);

SET @scenario1 = 3;
SET @DAY_START = 0;
SET @DAY_END = 7;
SET @TRAIN_TYPE = 'Empty Train';
SET @TRACK_TYPE = 'East Track';

DECLARE @KM_START INT;
DECLARE @KM_END INT;

SET @KM_START = 0;
SET @KM_END = 200;

WITH movement
     AS (SELECT m.scenariopid,
                m.legid,
                Substring(routedata, 1, 23)                   AS RoutePart,
                Substring(routedata, 24, Len(routedata) - 23) AS RouteData,
                Len(routedata) / 23 - 1                       AS cnt,
                1                                             AS sequence,
                m.starttime
         FROM   output.movement m
         WHERE  scenariopid = @scenario1
                AND m.starttime BETWEEN ( @DAY_START * 86400 ) AND
                                        ( @DAY_END * 86400 )
         UNION ALL
         SELECT scenariopid,
                legid,
                Substring(m1.routedata, 1, 23)                      AS RoutePart
                ,
                Substring(m1.routedata, 24,
                Len(m1.routedata) - 23) AS RouteData,
                Len(m1.routedata) / 23 - 1                          AS cnt,
                sequence + 1                                        AS sequence,
                m1.starttime
         FROM   movement m1
         WHERE  m1.cnt > 0),
     casttable
     AS (SELECT tt.scenariopid,
                tt.legid,
                tt.sequence,
                tt.trackid,
                tt.offset,
                tt.timeoffset,
                tr.[length],
                tt.starttime
         FROM   (SELECT scenariopid,
                        legid,
                        sequence,
                        Cast(trackidbin AS SMALLINT) AS TrackID,
                        Sign(Cast(offsetbin AS BIGINT)) *
                        ( 1.0 +
                        ( Cast(offsetbin AS BIGINT) & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF ) *
                        Power(Cast(2 AS FLOAT), -52) )
                        *
                        Power(Cast(2 AS FLOAT), ( Cast(offsetbin AS BIGINT) &
                                                  0x7ff0000000000000
                                                ) /
                        0x0010000000000000
                        - 1023)                      AS Offset,
                        Cast(timebin AS INT)         AS TimeOffset,
                        starttime                    AS StartTime
                 FROM   (SELECT legid,
                                scenariopid,
                                sequence,
                                Substring(routepart, 9, 2)  AS TrackIDBin,
                                Substring(routepart, 11, 8) AS OffsetBin,
                                Substring(routepart, 19, 4) AS TimeBin,
                                starttime
                         FROM   movement) t) tt
                INNER JOIN input.track tr
                        ON tr.trackid = tt.trackid
                           AND tr.scenariopid = tt.scenariopid)
SELECT *
FROM   casttable
ORDER  BY legid,
          sequence
OPTION (maxrecursion 20000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Numbers Table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) (zero-based assumed below) to create CTE *movement* like this:

```
WITH movement
     AS (SELECT m.scenariopid,
                m.legid,
                Substring(routedata, n.N*23 + 1, 23)  AS RoutePart,
                n.N                                   AS cnt,
       --         1                                   AS sequence,  -- use a row_number function here instead, as per your vendor.
                m.starttime
         FROM   output.movement m
         JOIN Numbers n
            on n < Len(routedata) / 23 
         WHERE  scenariopid = @scenario1
                AND m.starttime BETWEEN ( @DAY_START * 86400 ) AND
                                        ( @DAY_END * 86400 )
),
-- etc.
```

If you don't have a static Numbers Table, [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73067/create-multiple-variable-columns-from-single-column-value/73070#73070) demonstrates how to create one dynamically in a CTE.

Comment: Pieter, Thank you very much for the response. Ok I see the potential value in a Numbers table like this, but could you advise on what exactly should go in the numbers table? Is it just incremented numbers (from 0 to x) or is the numbers table populated from a select statement or data unique to my db? As in, is this numbers table a very general thing that can be used in any situation or must it be tweaked depending on the situation? It seems very general and too good to be true from reading the link you gave. Maybe I am just naive. I sincerely appreciate the response.

Comment: @Nick_UF: Recommended practice would be to create a static Number table sufficient for commonly used queries, and CROSS JOIN it as necessary for larger queries. Jeff Moden works with 30 year mortgages so has a static 0 - 11,000 Numbers table, since 30 * 365.25 is slightly less than 11,000. Some developers have a separate static DATES table, while others generate one dynamically from the more general NUMBERS table.

Comment: A million times thank you. This has solved my problem.